# VUEJs : import service in main.js

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I did create a service for authentication in vuejs

```
import axios from "axios";

var authenticateService = {
  login: function(Username, Password) {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("username", Username);
    form.append("password", Password);
    return axios.post(LOGIN_API, form);  
  }
}

export default authenticateService;
```

I want to use this service in my main.js, where I have got an axios interceptor. I have interceptor which relogins if received any 401 response from server

```
import authenticateService from "./service/AuthenticationService";
import axios from "axios";

axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {

  let res = err.response;
  if (res.status === 401 && res.config && !res.config.__isRetryRequest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      authenticateService//Error here. authenticateService undefined
      .login('user1username', 'user1password')
        .then(result => {
          localStorage.setItem("expire_time", response.data.expires_in);
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access_token);
          err.config.__isRetryRequest = true;
          err.config.headers.Authorization =
            "Bearer " + response.data.access_token;
          resolve(err);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          localStorage.removeItem("expire_time");
          localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
          reject(e);
        });
    });
  }
});
```

This interceptor throws error saying "authenticateService is not defined". Though I have imported the authenticateService, I get it undefined. Not sure what I did wrong here.

**Edit** return axios object from login function

Comment: This is very curious. It works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/v32xw05o8y